# ResourceDictionary in WPF class library

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, class-library

I have a `Class Library` with the following bits of code.

Below is my `UserControl`'s `Resource`:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Mine.Controls;component/Templates.xaml" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And below here is my `ResourceDictionary` file named *Templates.xaml*:

**Build action:** Resource

**Copy to ...:** Do not copy

**Custom tool:**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyButton"
                     TargetType="Button">
        <Border x:Name="buttonBorderOuter"
                BorderBrush="#DBDBDB"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Background="#00ECECEC"
                CornerRadius="5" />
    </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I then get the error

> Exception: An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "pack://application:,,,/Mine.Controls;component/Templates.xaml".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you use Visual 2012

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change the build action for `Templates.xaml` to `Page`.

Comment: Tnx, that did the job :)